# What are and how do I delete "spurious" artifacts?

Tags: qgis

I dissolved the inner polygons of a shp file and was left with some lines inside. I'm not sure how they got there, since the original file does not seem to have them. I've also tried deleting them, but have not been able to do so.

[image]